# Sending attachments with PHPMailer library

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, phpmailer

Currently I have a table where I'm displaying all my records. Now I have a functionality to export the table data to an excel sheet. Now when I click export the excel sheet goes to my `C:\Xammp\htdocs` folder. The following is the code I'm using to save the excel sheet.

```
function listing_export_allxls()
    {
        $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
        $arrlistings = $this->input->post('listing');
        $lists = str_replace('-', ',', $arrlistings);
        $arrLists = $this->listings_model->exportallxls($lists = '');
        $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Listing Sales');
        $sheet->getStyle("A1")->getFont()->setSize(16);
        $i = 0;
        $row = 3;
        $Column = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F');
        // Header
        $column_title = array('Ref No', 'Name', 'For', 'Unit No.', 'Unit Type', 'Development');
        for ($i = 0; $i <= count($column_title) - 1; $i++) {
            $index = $Column[$i] . $row;
            $sheet->setCellValue($index, $column_title[$i]);
        }
        // Rows
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($arrLists); $j++) {
            $row++;
            $sheet->setCellValue('A' . $row, $arrLists[$j]['refno']);
            $sheet->setCellValue('B' . $row, $arrLists[$j]['proptitle']);
            $sheet->setCellValue('C' . $row, $arrLists[$j]['property_for']);
            $sheet->setCellValue('D' . $row, $arrLists[$j]['unitno']);
            $sheet->setCellValue('E' . $row, $arrLists[$j]['ctitle']);
        }
        $sheet->getStyle('A3:M3')->getFill()
            ->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)
            ->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFA0A0A0');
        $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
        $writer->save('all_listings_' . date('dmyhis') . '.xls');
        $attachment = ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'all_listings_' . date('dmyhis') . '.xls');
        $this->send_mail_excel('test@email.com', 'test', 'test',$attachment, '', '');
    }
```

Now here I'm saving the file name to `$attachment` and I'm writing the following in my send_email function:

```
function send_mail_excel($emailto, $subject, $message, $attachment, $agentemail = "", $agentname = "")
{
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/application/libraries/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php');
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/application/libraries/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php');
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/application/libraries/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php');

    $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();

    try {
        //Server settings                   
        $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";                             //Set the SMTP server to send through
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
        $mail->Port       = 465;

        $mail->Username = "xxx";
        $mail->Password = 'xxx';
        $mail->SetFrom("xxx");
        //multiple recepients
        if (strrpos($emailto, ',') > 0) {
            $recipients = explode(',', $emailto);
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($recipients as $email) {
                if ($i == 0) {

                    $mail->addAddress($email);
                    $mail->AddCC($email);
                    if($agentemail){
                        $mail->addReplyTo($agentemail, $agentname);
                    }
                }
                ++$i;
            }
        } else {
            $mail->addAddress($emailto);
            $mail->AddCC($emailto);
            if($agentemail){
                $mail->addReplyTo($agentemail, $agentname);
            }
        }

        //Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body = $message;
        $mail->addAttachment($attachment);
        $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

        $mail->send();
        $msg = 'Message has been sent';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $msg = "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    }
    return $msg;
}
```

Now here I'm able to successfully get my email, but it only shows me the subject and message, but no attachments were attached. So where exactly am I going wrong with adding my attachment here?

**EDIT:** So I found out the problem. I did a print on $attachment and it showed me `C:/Xammp/htdocs/all_listings_260122084136.xls` meanwhile the filename in my actual folder is `C:/Xammp/htdocs/all_listings_260122084135.xls`. So how can I get the same filename in this case. The method I put seems to not work

Comment: First check exactly what is in $attachment, and that it points to a file that really exists and that can be read by the user this runs as, then check the return value from addAttachment, which will return false if it can’t read the file.

Comment: @Synchro okay, it seems I got the problem. The $attachment show me `C:/Xammp/htdocs/all_listings_260122084136.xls` meanwhile the filename in my actual folder is `C:/Xammp/htdocs/all_listings_260122084135.xls`. So how can I get the same filename in this case. The method I put seems to not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because you are generating the filename twice, and it's time-dependent, so it can be different each time. Define it once in a variable and then use it for both things:

```
$attachment = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'all_listings_' . date('dmyhis') . '.xls';
$writer->save($attachment);
$this->send_mail_excel('test@email.com', 'test', 'test', $attachment, '', '');
```